# Complex inequalities Cartesian equation

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers, locus

So I got the following problem and I wanted to solve and find the region using the Cartesian equations. However when I found the Cartesian equations and graphed the regions the answer is incorrect. Can anyone show me where I went wrong ?
[image]

My solution 
[image: my solution]

Comment: Plotting using the original definition seems straightforward. In any case the inequality describing the circular region should be $(x-1)^2+y^2\leqslant 4$.

Comment: But what would be the correct inequality for the argument ?

Comment: Check out '''atan2'''. You may be encountering an issue involving '''atan'''.

Answer (score 1):

Your only error is to set $(x-1)^2+y^2\leq2$, even if the correct one is: $$(x-1)^2+y^2\leq4$$
The other calculation are correct.